# Convert date to a string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a date "2016/02/22" which I want to make more readable for the end user. I have tried using the `toString()` method but no such luck.

Eg. "Monday 2nd February 2016"

Any help appreciated thanks.

Comment: which format are you looking for?

Comment: What output is desired for 2016/02/22?

Comment: Something along the lines of Monday 2nd February 2016

Comment: @Brian If you want a very specific output (rather than `Date.toString()` which gives `Mon Feb 22 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Romance Standard Time)` and `Date.toDateString()` which gives `Mon Feb 22 2016`), then [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) might be worth taking a look at. It's fully customizeable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var d = new Date("2016/02/22");
console.log(d.toDateString());
```

It would be better if you mention the format in which you want the date to be displayed.

Comment: Edited my question sorry. This was the answer i was looking for thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var dateObj = new Date(Date.parse("2016/02/22"));
var week = [ "Sunday", "Monday", "Tueday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday" ];
var month = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];
var displayWeek = week[dateObj.getDay()];
var displayDate = dateObj.getDate();
switch(displayDate)
{
   case 1: displayDate = "1st"; break;
   case 2: displayDate = "2nd"; break;
   case 3: displayDate = "3rd"; break;
   case 21: displayDate = "21st"; break;
   case 22: displayDate = "22nd"; break;
   case 23: displayDate = "23rd"; break;
   case 31: displayDate = "31st"; break;
   default: displayDate += "th"; break;
}
var displayMonth = month [dateObj.getMonth()];
var displayYear = dateObj.getFullYear();
console.log( displayWeek  + " " + displayDate  + " " + displayMonth + " " + displayYear  );
```